# Curve of MAPs to evaluate training progress of Mask RCNN on synthetic data

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

Is MAP (Mean Average Precision) a good substitute for measuring training and validation accuracy at different stages of training a machine learning model for object detection?

I am retraining a Mask RCNN (pretrained on MS-COCO) on synthetic images(with five classes) and the validation loss seems to fluctuate up and down till the 1600th epoch although the training loss goes down. I have calculated the Mean Average Precision at every 100th epoch on both training data and validation data as well and I don't know what to make of it.

[image: Shown below is Mean Average Precision (from 0 to 1 scale on the y axis) and the number of epochs on the x axis]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your graph, MAP is not very informative. MAP does not appear to change as a function of epochs.

You also mention loss and accuracy, those numbers might be more informative.